# Whats wrong I get all the names twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the names twice and I need them to appear only once instead. How can I fix it?

I am using the SQL SELECT, stated below:

```
SELECT
    ( LTRIM(SUBSTRING(resource.name, CHARINDEX(',', resource.name) + 1, LENGTH(resource.name) - CHARINDEX(',', resource.name)))) AS firstname,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '') FROM 1 FOR POSITION(',' IN REPLACE(resource.name, '*Deleted*', '' ))-1))) AS lastname,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(obj  SEPARATOR ', ') FROM rel_raci resource_raci_r WHERE resource_raci_r.PERSON_ID = resource.id AND resource_raci_r.RACI ='R' AND getOrgtype(obj_id) = 6 ) AS companycode,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(obj, '*Deleted*', '')) FROM rel_raci resource_raci_r WHERE resource_raci_r.PERSON_ID = resource.id AND resource_raci_r.RACI ='R' AND getOrgtype(obj_id) = 4  ) AS organizationalunit,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(obj SEPARATOR ', ') FROM rel_raci resource_raci_r WHERE resource_raci_r.RACI ='R'  ) AS responsible,
     resource.identifier AS identifier,
    resource.phone AS phone,
    organisation.keywords AS keywords,
    resource.keywords AS persno,
    resource.id AS obj_id,
    resource.mobile AS mobile, 
    resource.e_mail AS email,
    resource.alias AS alias,
    resource.city AS city,
    resource.postcode AS postcode,
    resource.state AS state,
    resource.street AS street,
    resource.country AS country

    FROM obj_resource resource

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  rel_raci resource_raci ON resource.ID = resource_raci.PERSON_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN obj_resource organisation on  organisation.ID =  resource_raci.OBJ_ID

     -- Gibt nur die markierten Massnahmen aus
    WHERE CONTAINS($P{TE_SELECTIONS}, resource.id, -1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please format your question so it's in a readable format?

Comment: I already saw the failure must be in the Joins

Comment: Try using `SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement`

Comment: @manev at the lastname you mean? I think the failure is in the Joins

Comment: Don't just dump query, and expect us to understand what it does.  For us it's just a pile of junk code.

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do.  Then provide table structures, sample input, expected output.  Then describe the logic of what you query supposed to do.  And if people understand what you want, then maybe one of them can help you.

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask